# Frama-c execution time & heap memory bounds proof

Tags: frama-c

Does Frama-C provide any tools for proving the run-time characteristics of a function such as execution time (possibly as instruction count) and heap memory space (counted as bytes allocated)?

Answer (score 2):

#### Concerning execution time estimation

Frama-C works at the C level. The Metrics plug-in can provide a few metrics (such as statement count) on a version of the source very close to the original one (`-metrics -metrics-ast cabs`), or on the normalized source (often referred to as *Cil code*) that it uses. However, it does not have any knowledge of assembly code, therefore it cannot provide precise information about execution time at this level.

Since compiler optimizations impact code generation, the numbers given by Frama-C may or may not be close to what will be produced by a compiler, depending on which optimizations are enabled, what is known about the compiler and the target architecture, etc. In the general case, Frama-C cannot give any guarantees; in specific situations, it is possible to develop plug-ins to provide some of this information (e.g. the [Cost plug-in, mentioned here](https://bts.frama-c.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=mantis:frama-c:publications#external_plug-ins) uses annotations to try and maintain some correspondence between source and compiled code, and then uses them to provide some execution time information).

#### Concerning memory size estimation

There is an option, `-metrics-locals-size`, which does a rough estimation of the *stack* memory usage by a function. As in the previous case, this is only an estimation based on the source code. Compilers are likely to stack-allocate temporary variables for computing temporary subexpressions, or for register spilling, so the numbers given by Frama-C cannot be used in a worst-case stack estimation.

Dynamic memory allocation is supported in ACSL, so in theory it is possible to write annotations concerning it. However, current plug-ins do not provide a direct way to handle this precisely; it might require writing a new plug-in or, at least, an abstract domain for Eva.

Eva currently handles dynamic allocation, but probably not precisely enough for estimating heap size in an interesting way. It is possible to develop an abstract domain for Eva that would keep track of this information (adding `malloc`s and subtracting `free`s) and compute an *overapproximation* of the heap memory space, but this would require being able to bound the number of iterations of loops containing allocations (otherwise the upper bound would be infinite). Precision would depend on the complexity of the program.

For runtime verification, the E-ACSL plug-in already tracks some stack/heap information usage (even though it is not currently exported to the user), so in theory one could write an assertion similar to `//@ assert heap_size <= \old(heap_size) + 42;`, and have it checked at runtime, when running the instrumented program.

Answer (score 1):

To complement anol's answer, the [PathCrawler](http://pathcrawler-online.com:8080) plug-in (online version can be used freely, but the plugin itself is proprietary) has been used to generate sets of test cases covering all paths of C functions. This [article](http://pathcrawler-online.com:8080/pubs/wcet05.pdf) explains under which assumptions this can be used as the basis for WCET measurement, but basically the issues are the one already mentioned by anol: without a precise knowledge of the work done by the compiler and of the underlying hardware, which is not something Frama-C provides natively, things are going to be quite rough.

There has been apparently some recent work taking the same route of using PathCrawler for generating execution traces covering a sufficiently large proportion of the search space as a [bachelor project](https://esc.fnwi.uva.nl/thesis/centraal/files/f161473562.pdf) in Amsterdam.